# Why is an explicit cast required when returning a type intersection?

Tags: java, casting

[Nicolai Parlog's blog post on intersection types with `var`](https://nipafx.dev/java-var-intersection-types/) shows a method, `createCloseableIterator()`, that returns an intersection type:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Closeable & Iterator<String>>
        T createCloseableIterator(boolean empty) {
    if (empty)
        return (T) new Empty();
    else
        return (T) new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

where `Empty` and `Scanner` both implement `Iterator<String>` and `Closeable`.

Why are the explicit casts to `(T)` needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not because of the type intersection, it's because you're returing a `T`, which is chosen by the caller of the method and could be a different type that is not a `Scanner` or an `Empty`.

This would result in a class cast exception if you attempt to store the result in a variable of the other chosen type, for example:

```
class Other implements Closeable, Iterator<String> { ... }

Other e = createCloseableIterator(false);
```